# Is it possible to equate the Output of solving Single Variable Linear Inequality with Python's numpy ranges?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I've been browsing everywhere to find the answer but nothing. So I tried it myself with code like below but still failed.

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
x = symbols("x", real=True)
init_printing(use_unicode=True)
ekpr = (3*x - 2 < 2*x + 1)
sol = [solve(ekpr, x) for x in np.arange(0, 5, 1)]
sol
```

the output is like this:

```
3⋅x - 2 < 2⋅x + 1
[<3, <3, <3, <3, <3]
```

The output I want is: 0, 1 and 2 as this corresponds to x < 3.

Or other than numpy range, get it in some other way?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You are using `sympy` solve.  `numpy` adds nothing here.

Comment: are you trying to find the values in the array where the inequality is True? you may be looking for `.subs()`

Comment: I didn't try to find the value in the array of inequalities, because I got the output that is x < 3, but the problem is I want to change x < 3 automatically to 0, 1, and 2, this can't be done by subs, because subs works instead of all instance of the variable.

Comment: you may just want two variables, then you will be able to fill and solve

Comment: But I tried arange numpy so that it can automatically change the output x < 3, to 0, 1, and 2.

Comment: Maybe you already know how to solve it, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to carefully re-use `x`, substitute the values from your array and see if the result is `True`

```py
>>> x = symbols("x")
>>> ekpr = (3*x - 2 < 2*x + 1)
>>> [n for n in np.arange(5) if ekpr.subs({x: n})]
[0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: amazing, sir really helped my trouble,

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> (3*x - 2 < 2*x + 1).as_set() & Range(5)  # use set ops for univariate expression
{0, 1, 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it may help to use the lambdify function for sympy expressions (https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html). With that, I could get to a kind of workaround, although it's not really clean because you must make assumptions about the set of numbers for which the condition is fulfilled (for example, I restrict the search to the range [0, 100]):

```py
from sympy import *
x = symbols("x", real=True)
expression = x<3
expr_lambda = lambdify(x, expression)
list = []
for i in range(100):
    if expr_lambda(i):
        list.append(i)
print (list)
```

From this, I get the output

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort of help, but what I want is to automatically change the output x < 3 to 0, 1, and 3.

Comment: You mean 0, 1, and 2, right? Because this is precisely what my code does. You just have to take your result instead of "expression" in the example